# How to make a login form and redirects into seperate windows forms

Tags: c#, mysql, server

I cannot separate these Boolean into 3 windows forms. I cannot separate these things into 3 roles (Admin, Secretary, and Treasurer.) because these is a boolean. How to solve these problem? Please help me regarding this issue. Thanks.

**frm_Login:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace BarangayLigasRecordingSystemWEBPROG4
{
    public partial class frm_Login : Form
    {
        private string conn;
        private MySqlConnection connect;
        public frm_Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void db_connection()
        {
            try
            {
                conn = "Server=localhost;Database=brgyligasrecordingsystem;Uid=root;Pwd=1234;";
                connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
                connect.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }


        private bool validate_login(string user, string pass)
        {
            db_connection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from loginsignupdata where username=@username and password=@password";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pass);
            cmd.Connection = connect;
            MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (login.Read())
            {
                connect.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                connect.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string user = tbx_username.Text;
            string pass = tbx_password.Text;
            if (user == "" || pass == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill up this field.", "Empty Fields!");
                return;
            }
            bool r = validate_login(user, pass);
            if (r)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OK!");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("The username or password is incorrect!", "Wrong Credentials");
        }

        private void tbx_password_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm_Signup f2 = new frm_Signup();
            Hide();
            f2.ShowDialog();
            Close();
        }

        private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: How do you specify three values in a `boolean`,

Comment: where is Boolean section, I couldnt see. You can use integer, 0 admin 1 secretary  2 tresurer

Comment: @onur : Why Integer? why not `enum`?

Comment: Enum can be better. But you can directly use int type in every form.

Comment: why dont you specify your user roles in your database? if user login is success then get user role from query and use the value as you want

Answer (score 0):

A boolean value is limited two values (true or false) or three if you use a nullable boolean

```
        bool b1 = true;
        bool b2 = false;

        bool? b3 = null;
```

An enum on the other hand can contain a lot more values, and can be accessed using an integer. Here is an example of using an enum:

```
public class Program
{
    public enum Roles
    {
        Admin, 
        Secretary, 
        Treasurer
    }

    public class User
    {
        public Roles Role { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        User bob = new User(){ Role = Roles.Admin };

        switch (bob.Role)
        {
            case Roles.Admin:
                Console.WriteLine("This user is an Admin (use the admin login)");
                break;
            case Roles.Secretary:
                Console.WriteLine("This user is a Secretary (use the secretary login)");
                break;
            case Roles.Treasurer:
                Console.WriteLine("This user is a Treasurer (use the treasurer login)");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

an enum is a type, and can therefore be used throughout your program without explicitly making it static

```
private Roles validate_login(string user, string pass)
    {
        db_connection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from loginsignupdata where username=@username and password=@password";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pass);
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (login.Read())
        {
            connect.Close();
            // return true;
            // Instead of returning true, return the role of the user
        }
        else
        {
            connect.Close();
            // return false;
            // Instead of returning false, throw an exception, or reserve an enum for failed logins
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will require an additional field in your database so that the user field knows the role of the user, which can be saved and loaded from the database when the user logs in